# How far we should go when a problem asks us to express a vector as linear combination of the given basis?

Tags: linear-algebra

I must express every $v = (x,y,z)$ as a linear combination of the basis: $$v_1 = (1,1,0),\: v_2 = (1,0,1),\: v_3 = (0,1,1)$$

So i dont understand how far should i go. I dont think that this would be enough:

$$(x,y,z) = c_1(1,1,0) + c_2(1,0,1) + c_3(0,1,1)$$

So i thought that maybe i should find the inverse of $$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\1&0&1\\0&1&1\end{bmatrix} $$

Have that inverse multiplied by $(x,y,z)$ and with whatever we find as $c_1,c_2,c_3$ display $ c_1(1,1,0) + c_2(1,0,1) + c_3(0,1,1)$.

Would that be enough? Is it too little/too much?

Comment: I think the question is essentially asking you to represent $(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$ in terms of $\{v_i\}$

Comment: Of course, you are asked to express $c_1,c_2,c_3$ in terms of $v$.

Comment: For a shortcut, note that $\,v_1+v_2+v_3=2\cdot (1,1,1)\,$ so $(1,0,0)=\frac{1}{2}\,\cdot (v_1+v_2-v_3)\,$.

Answer (score 6):

You're supposed to find concrete expressions for $c_1,c_2,c_3$ as functions of $x,y,z$.

All the *calculation* is indeed in inverting the matrix, but part of the exercise is to show you understand how the entries of the inverse matrix become expressions for $c_1, c_2, c_3$.

Answer (score 4):

Yes your way is right, indeed we need $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$ such that

$$c_1v_1+c_2v_2+c_3v_3=v \iff \begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\1&0&1\\0&1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}c_1\\c_2\\c_3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$$

and the solution can be found by the inverse matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\1&0&1\\0&1&1\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$$

We denote $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$ as the components for a given vector $v=(x,y,z)$ in the basis $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$.